# UIWebView stops firing delegate methods after link is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in my app that I use to display locally saved HTML content. The content includes links whose sole purpose is to direct the application to display a different document. These links use a custom URL protocol: "jcom://", and the URL is a JSON string that tells the app how to find the document being linked.

You may question why we don't just use http URLs to link our documents. The answer to that isn't really relevant to the question at hand, and that detail can't be changed, also Because Reasons.

When one of these links is tapped, we use the `UIWebViewDelegate` method `webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool`. We can then decode the JSON payload and load the correct page.

The problem comes when a link doesn't reference a valid document. In that case, we want the user to be able to tap a different link on the same page. But after handling a single one of our jcom:// links, UIWebView stops sending us delegate methods when links are tapped.

I tried implementing a URLProtocol handler for the scheme, but all this does is stop UIWebView from generating load failures when links are tapped. Its methods also are not called once a single link has been tapped.

Does anyone know how I can restore the web view to a state where it will again allow taps on links? Thanks!

Comment: is the delegate function shouldStartLoadWith always returning true?

Comment: I've tried both and it doesn't make a difference either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up giving in to inevitability and just reloading the page. Not an ideal solution but a workable one in this particular case.